# How to plot histogram of multiple lists?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset with 13k Kickstarter projects and their tweets over the duration of a project. Each project contains a list with the number of tweets for each day, 
   e.g. `[10, 2, 4, 7, 2, 4, 3, 0, 4, 0, 1, 3, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 2, 3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0]`.

I've taken a subset of the data by setting the duration of the projects on 31 days so that each list has the same length, containing 31 values.

This piece of code prints each list of tweets:

```
    for project in data:
        data[project]["tweets"]
```

What is the easiest way to plot a histogram with matplotlib? I need a frequency distribution of the total number of tweets for each day. How do I count the values from each index? Is their an easy way using Pandas to do this?

The lists are also accessible in a Pandas data frame:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='index')
    df1 = df[['tweets']]
```

Comment: have you tried googling `matplotlib histogram`?

Comment: yes, examples only show if you have one list. Need to bring around 3000 lists down to one by accumulating values for each index in the lists @cel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Histogram* is probably not what you need. It's a good solution if you have a list of numbers (for example, IQs of people) and you want to attribute each number to a category (f.e. 79-, 80-99, 100+). There will be 3 bins and height of each bin will represent the quantity of numbers that fit in the corresponding category.

In your case, you already have the height of each bin, so (as I understand) what you want is a *plot* that looks like like a histogram. This (as I understand) is not supported by matplotlib and would require using matplotlib not the way it was intended to be used.

If you're OK with using plots instead of histograms, that's what you can do.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lists = [data[project]["tweets"] for project in data] # Collect all lists into one
sum_list = [sum(x) for x in zip(*lists)] # Create a list with sums of tweets for each day

plt.plot(sum_list) # Create a plot for sum_list
plt.show() # Show the plot
```

If you want to make a plot look like a histogram you should do that:

```
plt.bar(range(0, len(sum_list)), sum_list)
```

instead of plt.plot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're right about the histogram. The plot is good enough to draw conclusions from.

Comment: Found a way to make a plot look like a histogram, edited my answer. @MauriceStam

Comment: Does it solve your problem (displaying number of tweets written each day)? @MauriceStam

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I already created some plots for different durations. Really insightful. Didn't have that much experience with list comprehensions and the zip function.. Also will use your plt.bar addition. Need a little bit more credits to +1 your answer ;) @Илья Петеров

Comment: Glad I could help:) @MauriceStam